# Compact groupoid presentations for closed 2-orbifolds (or finite graphs of finite groups)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, stacks, groupoids

A result of [Noohi](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crelle.2010.067/html) says that if $\mathsf{X}$ and $\mathsf{Y}$ are topological stacks and $\mathsf{Y}$ admits a groupoid presentation $\mathcal{G}$ in which both $\mathcal{G}_0$ and $\mathcal{G}_1$ are compact, then the *mapping stack* $\operatorname{Map}(\mathsf{Y},\mathsf{X})$ is again a topological stack.

If $\mathsf{Y}$ is (the stack associated to) a closed, good 2-orbifold or a finite graph of finite groups, then $\mathsf{Y}$ is presented by the action groupoid of a finite group on a compact space (i.e. a closed surface or a finite graph), so Noohi's result applies.

My question arises from the observation that the "usual" ways to write down an étale groupoid representing either a closed 2-orbifold or a finite graph of finite groups do *not* yield groupoids where even the object space is compact. For example, for an orbifold, the object space is usually a disjoint union of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you're clever you can get away with finitely many open sets, but the open sets are certainly not compact.

My question is: is there a variation on the standard construction of a groupoid associated to an orbifold or a graph of groups that yields a compact space of objects and arrows in the case of a closed, good 2-orbifold or a finite graph of finite groups? I expect this groupoid is likely not étale; that's fine by me.

Even more concretely, consider the groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ whose object space is the disjoint union $[0,1] \sqcup [1,2]$ and which has exactly two nonidentity arrows identifying the copies of ${1}$. Is the stack $\mathsf{B}\mathcal{G}$ isomorphic to (the stack associated to) the closed interval?

Answer (score 1):

For the "even more concretely" part, I think we can say that yes, $\mathsf{B}\mathcal{G}$ is isomorphic to the interval.
Essentially because there is at most one arrow between any two points of $\mathcal{G}_0$, the orbit-space map $\mathcal{G}_0 \to [0,2]$ is a principal $\mathcal{G}$-bundle, defining by the Yoneda lemma a map $\underline{I} \to \mathsf{B}\mathcal{G}$. It seems pretty straightforward to show that this map is an isomorphism.

This *suggests* but does not prove that one could alter the usual definition of the étale groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ associated to an orbifold or a graph of groups by working with, for example, closed balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with finite group actions, or closed balls in trees equipped with $\mathscr{G}_v$ actions, and then glue along overlaps as usual. The resulting groupoid $\bar{\mathcal{G}}$ is of course not étale, but will have (if you're careful) a compact space of objects and arrows in the case of a closed 2-orbifold or a finite graph of finite groups.
If you take these balls to be contained in slightly larger *open* balls defining an étale groupoid presenting the orbifold or graph of groups, the inclusion $\iota\colon \bar{\mathcal{G}} \to \mathcal{G}$ is full, faithful and essentially surjective—at least, in a category-theoretic sense. Depending on your definition of equivalence, it may or may not be an equivalence of topological groupoids, essentially because that definition is catered towards *étale* (or merely open) groupoids, and $\mathcal{\bar{G}}$ is neither. Nevertheless, I believe it follows that $\mathsf{B}\bar{\mathcal{G}}$ and $\mathsf{B}\mathcal{G}$ are isomorphic as stacks, since the functor $\mathsf{B}$ is an equivalence of weak 2-categories? I'd love input on this last bit.